# Javascript resources for console like web applications?

Tags: javascript, console-application

Suppose I want to implement a curses/console like program in HTML/CSS/Javascript.  Examples might be a online text adventure game or a simple interpreter similar to the "Try the XYZ programming language now" web pages you see for languages like Ruby or Haskell.  Is there a library/plugin/etc... that implements these terminal like interfaces?

Note:

After digging around for quite some time I found [jquery-console](https://github.com/chrisdone/jquery-console), which looks quite promising at first glance.

Any other alternatives or recommendations?

Comment: [TryHaskell](http://tryhaskell.com/)'s footer says it uses jquery-console, so if you're looking for similar functionality that sounds like a good choice. You can make your own GitHub fork for custom features, too.

Comment: Hey, I have a little webapp I made for my Minecraft server. Goto http://termtm.com/sites/mcos/admin.html in chrome, and check it out. Also email me @ TERMtm@gmail.com and I probably could help you out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been using the [termlib.js](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/) library for a couple of projects and it works really great. It helps with a lot of stuff like handling keyboard and parsing inputs.

It should also be less bloated than any jQuery-based solution unless you were going to use jQuery anyway.

You might want to start off looking at the [readme](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/readme.txt) or try some [samples](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/samples.html).

Comment: I would probably use jQuery anyways, but this library looks quite nice.